# Turning a scrollview in xamarin forms into a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

is there a way I can take the contents of a scrollview and turn it into a pdf in my xamarin forms app? Would preferably want to do it for free.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/akgulebubekir/PDFSharp.Xamarin.Forms

Comment: great! the only problem Im having is actually initiallizing within my AppDelegate in my ios project. I get this error "The name 'PdfSharp' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
This is my code for my app delegate

Comment: Did you added the reference to that library?